# How to center this Entry widget?

Tags: python, graphics, authentication, widget, tkinter

I am starting a project in Python: an email client. I know it may sound odd, but it's just for fun.

I have an `Entry` widget and a `Canvas` widget. When I `pack` them both, It gives me the Canvas, and an Entry widget centred above the Canvas, with a border around the Canvas, therefore a border separating the Entry widget and the Canvas.

What I want is the Entry widget centred in the Canvas, with no borders dividing the Entry box and the Canvas.

When I set the master widget in the Entry widget to `canvas`, that canvas doesn't appear: only the Entry widget, with the window large enough only to contain the Entry widget.

If the master widget is set to `frame`, I get what I described above, the canvas and Entry widget separate, but the size of the whole window is as specifies.

This is my actual code:

```
import tkinter

frame = tkinter.Tk()
frame.config(height=370, width=670, bg="#C2C2D6")

entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, exportselection=0)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(frame, height=370, width=670, bg="#C2C2D6", 
                        bd=0, relief="sunken")
entry.pack()
canvas.pack()

frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the reason to use canvas with entry in it? You're going to draw something?

Comment: When you say "What I want is the Entry box centered in the canvas" do you literally mean you want the entry _inside_ the canvas? If so, do you expect the entry widget to move when you scroll the canvas or do you expect to always stay centered in the canvas?

Comment: @kalgasnik: I do not need the canvas, my frame is colored as needed. But without the canvas, I only get a small entry box in a window large enough only to contain the entry box. The canvas essentially gives me dimensions.

Comment: @Bryan: yes, I want the widget centered in the frame. As I said above, the canvas only gives dimensions. I've tried setting dimensions on the frame, but they won't appear when there is no canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `Canvas`. You can set `frame` as the parent of `entry`:

```
import tkinter

frame = tkinter.Tk()

frame.config(height=370, width=670, bg="#C2C2D6")
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, exportselection=0)
entry.pack(padx=100, pady=100, expand=1, fill='x')

frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh, so I simply use padx/pady? That should solve it...I'll test it in a bit? What is the fill=tkinter.X part mean?

Comment: `tkinter.X` ( == 'x') means that entry should expand only horizontally when you resize `frame`

Comment: This isn't quite the proper way to do it, though I guess it gives you the visual look you're after. This idea doesn't work very well when you start making more complex applications.

Comment: Please, explain what wrong with it and what is the better solution.

Comment: I know this is old, but @BryanOakley: how exactly would I do it better? I thought that it wouldn't be the best way to do it. I am trying grid() now, but it's a bit confusing, I have to get the feel for it. What do you suggest?